# How can I position different size creatures in a group automaticly

Tags: architecture, xna-4.0, design-patterns

I'm doing a game (in xna) on my free time, as I'm not in the game market, I'm pretty sure I'm missing something that would help me get this right.  Think of Ogre Battle. A group of unit moves, and when they cross enemy, a small automatic Final fantasy battle starts for 2 or 3 round.

I'm struggling on how I should place the creatures in the combat screen. A fight started. (final fantasy rpg battle ) The creatures part of this group needs to be positionned in a 16x16 grid. Some creatures are bigger and use larger than 1x1 square.

I create a class called group to represent groups of creature walking around. So far, I decide to put in an array of 4x4 representing the grid. How do I go around and position all the creatures on that grid and make sure they arent stepping on top of each other ?

some pseudo code I have right now :

```
 Class Group
  array(4,4) of rectangle
  array(4,4) of creature

  Public sub Update()
    adjustCreaturePosition
  end sub
End class

Class Creature
    CombatValue as List of Enum.Qualities
    PreferedPosition as Enum.Position
    Range as smallint( 1 = melee, 2 = small range, 3 = long range)
End Class 

 Public Enum Position
  Front
  Middle
  Back
 End Enum

 Public Enum Qualities
    Melee
    Armored
    Strengh
    Dodge
    Siege
    SmallRange
    DPS
    Nuker 
    Controller
    Buffer
    Dex
    Int    
    Sick   
    Weak
End Enum
```

In the update of the group class , I need to create a function to set the position of all creatures when the combat starts.

```
Private Sub AdjustCreaturePosition()
       ' check the "prefered position" of all creep ( front, middle, back).
       ' if there are no more spot left for a creature, I need to check which creature is moved to the middle row based on A. if one of the creature on the front row will be able to attack on middle row ( based on the range ). If no unit can attack from the middle row,  the weaker one is send on the back ( the sum of their combatValue list)  
    Next
End Sub
```

I got no idea how I'll do the AdjustCreaturePosition in a smart way yet. but lets say it works.
Where I'm at a loss is how should I handle large creature who needs a 2x2 grid ?

Comment: not sure at all about those tag, let me know if I should add/change them.

Comment: Some kind of image would really make this question more clear, at the moment it's written like a stream of consciousness. Keep it to one question per post, and be specific about your question. Keep in mind that there's no "best" way to do things. And frequently you'll get more help if you tell us what you've tried so we have something to work with.

Comment: Also see these related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28146/how-do-i-implement-group-formations-in-a-3d-rts http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/44361/unclutter-units-in-rts-game

Comment: not sure about those, this seems to be for pathfinding, and I'm good on that. its on the battle phase that I'm struggling ... I'll try to adjust the question.

Comment: The second question does not involve pathfinding. Thanks for working on the question.

Comment: I've not yet coded anything relevant to the battle screen yet, I'm still on the planning stage, and I dont want to start coding something that'll turn into a mess in a month and I'll have to delete and starts over.